# 70s young adult sci-fi novel about an heretic among the stars?

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm trying to identify a 70s (I think) young adult sci-fi novel.

The protagonist is a peasant in a culture established offworld. The culture has sunk to a basic agricultural level. The planet they are on doesn't have the required raw materials for tool use. His community is forced to pay a levy to The City (or something). Despite warnings to the contrary he travels there to confront the regime - and find out the truth.

Comment: And what is the truth?

Comment: That would be a spoiler - I remember enjoying it so don't really want to ruin it for others.

Comment: Found it!! Heritage of the Star  http://www.amazon.co.uk/Heritage-Star-Sylvia-Engdahl/dp/0575016698

Comment: That was easy. Now add it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Per Fuzz' own comment above, the answer was "[Heritage of the Star](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Heritage-Star-Sylvia-Engdahl/dp/0575016698)" (1973) by Sylvia Engdahl (also known as "This Star Shall Abide").

> *Noren knew that his world was not as it should be--it was wrong that only the Scholars, and their representatives the Technicians, could use metal tools and Machines. It was wrong that only they had access to the mysterious City, which he had always longed to enter. Above all, it was wrong for the Scholars to have sole power over the distribution of knowledge. The High Law imposed these restrictions and many others, though the Prophecy promised that someday knowledge and Machines would be available to everyone.
>
> Noren was a heretic. He defied the High Law and had no faith in the Prophecy's fulfillment. But the more he learned of the grim truth about his people's deprivations, the less possible it seemed that their world could ever be changed. It would take more drastic steps than anyone imagined to restore their rightful heritage.*

[image: book cover, purple-pinkish taint: bearded man in the foreground, several smaller characters' faces at the bottom]